# EntityFramework doesn't refresh navigation properties

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

I've got a simple relationship

[image]

I've created a simple app with the Model like the above one. Model in the application must be updated every time DB changes. I can get the latest changes by calling GetDBChanges Stored Procedure. (see method T1Elapsed)

here is the app:

```
class Program
{
    private static int? _lastDbChangeId;
    private static readonly MASR2Entities Model = new MASR2Entities();
    private static readonly Timer T1 = new Timer(1000);
    private static readonly Timer T2 = new Timer(1000);
    private static Strategy _strategy = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ctx = new MASR2Entities())
        {
            _lastDbChangeId = ctx.GetLastDbChangeId().SingleOrDefault();
        }
        _strategy = Model.Strategies.FirstOrDefault(st => st.StrategyId == 224);

        T1.Elapsed += T1Elapsed;
        T1.Start();

        T2.Elapsed += T2Elapsed;
        T2.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void T2Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("All rules: " + Model.StrategyRules.Count());
        Console.WriteLine("Strategy: name=" + _strategy.Name + " RulesCount=" + _strategy.StrategyRules.Count);
    }

    private static void T1Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        T1.Stop();
        try
        {
            using (var ctx = new MASR2Entities())
            {
                var changes = ctx.GetDBChanges(_lastDbChangeId).ToList();
                foreach (var dbChange in changes)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("DbChangeId:{0} {1} {2} {3}", dbChange.DbChangeId, dbChange.Action, dbChange.TableName, dbChange.TablePK);
                    switch (dbChange.TableName)
                    {
                        case "Strategies":
                            {
                                var id = Convert.ToInt32(dbChange.TablePK.Replace("StrategyId=", ""));
                                Model.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, Model.Strategies.AsEnumerable());
                            }
                            break;
                        case "StrategyRules":
                            {
                                var id = Convert.ToInt32(dbChange.TablePK.Replace("StrategyRuleId=", ""));
                                Model.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, Model.StrategyRules.AsEnumerable());
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    _lastDbChangeId = dbChange.DbChangeId;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            T1.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, this is a sample output:

```
All rules: 222
Strategy: name=Blabla2 RulesCount=6
```

then I add a row to the child table (Strategy Rule),

```
DbChangeId:1713 I StrategyRules StrategyRuleId=811
All rules: 223
Strategy: name=Blabla2 RulesCount=7
```

and finally, I remove the row from StrategyRules

```
DbChangeId:1714 D StrategyRules StrategyRuleId=811
All rules: 222
Strategy: name=Blabla2 RulesCount=7
```

Why RulesCount is still 7? How I can force EF to refresh "Navigation Property"?

What I am missing here?

**---EDIT---** to cover Slauma's answer

```
case "StrategyRules":
{
   var id = Convert.ToInt32(dbChange.TablePK.Replace("StrategyRuleId=", ""));
   if (dbChange.Action == "I")
   {
       //Model.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, Model.StrategyRules.AsEnumerable());       
   }
   else if (dbChange.Action == "D")
   {
      var deletedRule1 = Model.StrategyRules.SingleOrDefault(sr => sr.Id == id); 
      //the above one is NULL as expected

      var deletedRule2 = _strategy.StrategyRules.SingleOrDefault(sr => sr.Id == id);
      //but this one is not NULL - very strange, because _strategy is in the same context
      //_strategy = Model.Strategies.FirstOrDefault(st => st.StrategyId == 224);
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObjectContext.Refresh` refreshes the scalar properties of the entities you pass into the method [along with any keys that refer to related entities](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/3d9e5d1f-18fb-4c71-a304-7ef9e25339f6/). If an entity you pass into the method does not exist anymore in the database because it has been deleted in the meantime `Refresh` does nothing with the attached entity and just ignores it. (That's a guess from my side, but I could not explain otherwise why you 1) don't get an exception on `Refresh` (like "cannot refresh entity because it has been deleted") and 2) the entity is apparently still attached to the context.)

Your Insert case does not work because you call `Refresh` but it works because you load the whole `StrategyRules` table into memory in this line:

```
Model.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, Model.StrategyRules.AsEnumerable())
```

`Refresh` enumerates the collection in the second parameter internally. By starting the iteration it triggers the query which is just `Model.StrategyRules` = load the whole table. `AsEnumerable()` is only a switch from LINQ-to-Entities to LINQ-to-Objects, that is, every LINQ operator you would apply after `AsEnumerable()` is performed in memory, not on the database. Since you don't apply anything, `AsEnumerable()` actually has no effect on your query.

Because you load the whole table the recently inserted `StrategyRule` will be loaded as well and together will the key to the `_strategy` entity. The `ObjectContext`'s automatic relationship fixup establishes the relationship to the navigation collection in `_strategy` and `_strategy.StrategyRules.Count` will be `7`. (You could remove the `Refresh` call and just call `Model.StrategyRules.ToList()` and the result would still be `7`.)

Now, all this does not work in the Delete case. You still run a query to load the whole `StrategyRules` table from the database but EF won't remove or detach entities from the context that are not in the result set anymore. (And as far as I know there is no option to force such an automatic removal.) The deleted entity is still in the context with its key refering to `strategy` and the count will remain `7`.

What I am wondering is why you don't leverage that your set of `DBChanges` apparenty knows exactly what has been removed in the `dbChange.TablePK` property. Instead of using `Refresh` couldn't you use something like:

```
case "StrategyRules":
{
    switch (dbChange.Action)
    {
        case "D":
        {
            var removedStrategyRule = _strategy.StrategyRules
                .SingleOrDefault(sr => sr.Id == dbChange.TablePK);
            if (removedStrategyRule != null)
                _strategy.StrategyRules.Remove(removedStrategyRule);
        }
        break;

        case ...
    }
}
break;
```

Comment: First of all many thanks for the explanation. It makes sense and you are right, I don't need to call Refresh (got the same behavior without it) but how you explain this: Model.StrategyRules.SingleOrDefault(sr => sr.Id == myId) is null after DB delete but _strategy.StrategyRules.SingleOrDefault(sr => sr.Id == myId) in not null (it still holds the "deleted" rule). Basically _strategy.StrategyRules.Count = 7 but Model.StrategyRules.ToList() returns 6 items. So does it remove from the context or not? I'll add more code in the morning to make it clearer.

Comment: Secondly, nice suggestion with switch-case "D" stuff but I don't have _strategy object. (this is only example). Also I can't do Model.Strategies.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == ???); as don't know StrategyId (only StrategyRuleId). I was thinking about getting strategy object by calling Model.StrategyRules.SingleOrDefault(sr => sr.Id == myID).Strategy but it fails as StrategyRule is null (already deleted from the context)

Comment: @Novitzky: To your first comment. The deleted rule is **not** removed from the context. `Model.StrategyRules.ToList()` queries the database, not the context entries. So, it returns everything except the already deleted rule -> count = 6. `_strategy.StrategyRules` is the object graph in memory and it still has the deleted rule -> count = 7.

Comment: Thanks again. I've done a few tests and it works exactly like you explained.